# Django conditional aggregation

Tags: python, database, django, conditional-statements, aggregation

Does anyone know of how I would, through the django ORM, produce a query that conditionally aggregated related models?

Let's say, for example, that you run a site that sells stuff, and you want to know how much each employee has sold in the last seven days.  It's simple enough to do this over all sales:

```
q = Employee.objects.filter(type='salesman').annotate(total_sales = models.Sum('sale__total'))
```

assuming Employee and Sale models with a many-to-many relationship between them.  OK, but now how would I go about constraining this to all sales for the last seven days (or any arbitrary time frame)?  Does anyone know?

Comment: Are you asking about SELECT SUM(SALES) GROUP BY EMPLOYEE queries?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I guess I didn't think this through very far.  I didn't realize that filter handled things with a left join (though thinking on it, how else would it map to the db?), so the obvious answer is:

```
Employee.objects.filter(type='salesman').filter(sale__timestamp__gte = start_date)\
        .exclude(sale__timestamp__gte = end_date).annotate(...
```